# Tried using pip to install visualization

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

So, I tried installing the `visualization` module (https://pypi.org/project/visualization/) in python using the `pip install visualization` from which I get this output -

```
Collecting visualization
Using cached visualization-0.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\sohan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from visualization) (1.19.0)
Collecting autolab-perception
  Using cached autolab_perception-0.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Collecting autolab-core
  Using cached autolab_core-0.0.14-py3-none-any.whl (73 kB)
Collecting trimesh[easy]
  Using cached trimesh-3.7.14-py3-none-any.whl (619 kB)
Collecting imageio
  Using cached imageio-2.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.3 MB)
Collecting pyrender
  Using cached pyrender-0.1.43-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting matplotlib<=2.2.0
  Using cached matplotlib-2.2.0.tar.gz (37.2 MB)
```

And this error -

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\sohan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\sohan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dhk3_0ty\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sohan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dhk3_0ty\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\sohan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-qk4saili'
         cwd: C:\Users\sohan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dhk3_0ty\matplotlib\
    Complete output (61 lines):
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [2.2.0]
                    python: yes [3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019,
                            00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]]
                  platform: yes [win32]

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                     numpy: yes [version 1.19.0]
          install_requires: yes [handled by setuptools]
                    libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
                  freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype
                            (freetype2\ft2build.h) could not be found.  You may
                            need to install the development package.]
                       png: no  [The C/C++ header for png (png.h) could not be
                            found.  You may need to install the development
                            package.]
                     qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'libqhull' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]

    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
               sample_data: yes [installing]
                  toolkits: yes [installing]
                     tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
            toolkits_tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                    macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                    qt5agg: no  [PySide2 not found; PyQt5 not found]
                    qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
                   gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
                 gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                    gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                     tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                            Tk]
                     wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                       gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                       agg: yes [installing]
                     cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
                 windowing: yes [installing]

    OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                    dvipng: no
               ghostscript: no
                     latex: no
                   pdftops: no

    OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                      dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    ============================================================================
                            * The following required packages can not be built:
                            * freetype, png
                            * Please check http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packa
                            * ges/freetype.htm for instructions to install
                            * freetype
                            * Please check http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packa
                            * ges/libpng.htm for instructions to install png
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I've tried using `pip3` as well, but no luck. I'm using Windows.

Comment: it has code on GitHub with place for [issues](https://github.com/BerkeleyAutomation/visualization/issues) - so send problem to author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use python 3.6 or you can build it from the source

and judging by your error, you are probably using different version and pip is trying to build it from the source. The error is because you don't have visual studio build tools installed. install it and it will solve your error
[get it from here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)